# How to numerically approximate solutions to a set of two second order two-variable PDEs using a python script (boundary value problem)?

Tags: python, numerical-methods, calculus, pde

I have a set of two PDEs like so (pseudo-code):

```
r'' = (s')^2 * r - G*M*r^-2
r' = -(r*s'')/(2*s')
```

`s` and `r` are functions of time, `'` the derivative, `G` and `M` are constants.

They were obtained from the Euler-Lagrange equations for the moon moving around the earth in 2D polar coordinates. *They may even be wrong; their correctness is not the point of this question.*

I have tried to go about solving them using the `scipy` library but it requires me to first separate the equations into first order ODEs such that each equation contains either r or s but not both. I frankly don't know how to do that and whilst this may be possible for these two equations, for the more complex versions I plan on working with it is unlikely to be achievable.

**So my question is:** How can I go about solving them directly without any manipulation? Are there any libraries out there that will do that?

Also, this is a boundary value problem. I know values of r and s at the start and end of my given time interval (from the JPL ephemerides) but not `r'` or `s'`.

EDIT:
After looking at the comments I put together some code with scipy:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import solve_ivp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from skyfield.api import load, Topos

G = 6.67430e-11
M = 5.97219e24

eph = load("de421.bsp")
observer = eph["earth"] + Topos(latitude_degrees=0, longitude_degrees=0)
moon = eph["moon"]

time1 = load.timescale().utc(2000, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0)
moon_position = observer.at(time1).observe(moon)
theta0, _, r0 = moon_position.radec()
time2 = load.timescale().utc(2000, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1)
moon_position = observer.at(time2).observe(moon)
theta1, _, r1 = moon_position.radec()

theta0 = float(theta0.radians)
thetadot = theta0 - float(theta1.radians)
r0 = float(r0.m)
rdot = r0 - float(r1.m)
print(r0, r1.m)
print(theta0, theta1.radians)
print(thetadot, rdot)


def equations(t, y):
    theta, r, thetadot, rdot = y
    dydt = [rdot, (thetadot**2 * r - G * M / r**2), thetadot, -r * (thetadot**2) / (2 * rdot),]
    return dydt


t_eval = np.linspace(0, 10000, 1000000)
sol = solve_ivp(equations, [0, 10000], [r0, theta0, rdot, thetadot])
t_plot = sol.t
y_plot = sol.y

#plt.plot(t_plot, y_plot[0], label="r(t)")
plt.plot(t_plot, y_plot[1], label="theta(t)")
plt.xlabel("Time")
plt.ylabel("Values")
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Unfortunately no matter how long or short my timescale is theta always becomes 0 at the end which can't be correct. Also the way I'm representing the system of equations in the equations function is wrong, how would I do it correctly?

Comment: they look more to a system of ODEs and not PDEs

Comment: I think you will need to know the initial conditions for `r'` and `s'` to have any hope here. The JPL ephemerides is able to provide both positions and velocities, so double check that.

Comment: Thanks @Matt Pitkin, after looking at the comments I've tried to create some code using scipy and I have used JPL data to find r' and s'. I'm still confused on how to represent my  equations in my code though, I'll attach it to the question.

Comment: As an example, see e.g., https://github.com/mattpitkin/random_scripts/blob/master/SolSym.ipynb.

Comment: Actually, you SHOULD start by making sure that the equations are correct - sympy might then have a chance of solving them. Fundamentally, you should end up with two invariants - total energy and total angular momentum.

Answer (score 1):

For an attempt at finding an analytical solution (although I note that the question asks for a numerical approximation), you could try using [sympy](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/index.html), in particular the [`dsolve_system`](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/solvers/ode.html#sympy.solvers.ode.systems.dsolve_system) function, e.g.,

```
from sympy import *
from sympy.solvers.ode.systems import dsolve_system

s, r, G, M, t = symbols("s r G M t")

sf = Function(s)(t)
rf = Function(r)(t)

sp = Derivative(sf, t)  # derivative
spp = Derivative(sf, (t, 2))  # second derivative

rp = -(r * spp) / (2 * sp)
rpp = sp**2 * r - G * M / r**2

eqs = [Eq(Derivative(rf, t), rp), Eq(Derivative(rf, (t, 2)), rpp)]

dsolve_system(eqa, t=t)
```

Unfortunately, it seems that sympy can't solve this system of equations analytically.

Comment: ... or that the system has no exact solution:) From the OP: _"They may even be wrong"_

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will note down sympy for use in future with other differential equations.  I also was wondering about your comment @cards - whilst it's entirely possible that I made a mistake in the formulation of the equations, I never expected to have an exact solution - instead one approximated through numerical methods. Is that what you meant or am I missing something?

Comment: Sympy will attempt to find a exact analytical solution rather than doing a numerical approximation. So, I think scipy's `odeint` function will be the way to go for you https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.odeint.html#scipy.integrate.odeint. I'll update my answer to give an example.

Comment: @AtomProgrammer no, that's not what I meant:) Sympy is tool for symbolic computation so try find exact solution [also if it supports numerical approximation, `nsolve`]... but, mathematically, not every problem has a solution that can be expressed in an exact way but only numerically: think of `integral from -oo to X of exp(-x^2) dx`. Further, the solver could be "limited" for certain problem

Answer (score 1):

You need to decide on one order of state components and keep to it.

At the moment you unpack

```
theta, r, thetadot, rdot = y
```

but you assemble the derivatives in the order

```
r, rdot, theta, thetadot
```

This can not work.

The initial values then have a still different order

```
r0, theta0, rdot, thetadot
```

Answer (score 0):

In your equations, r is radius and s is polar angle (I’ll use theta below). If you multiply your second equation by 2.r.sdot and rearrange you get

[image]

or

[image]

Hence you have a first invariant

[image]

h is the angular momentum (per unit mass) and it is constant because gravity is a central force, so imparts no torque and hence no change of angular momentum.

Substituting in your first equation you get

[image]

If you multiply through by rdot and rearrange you get

[image]

or

[image]

and hence you have a second invariant

[image]

E is the total energy (per unit mass) It will be negative for a bound orbit. It is constant because there are no external forces.

So, really, you have two first-order ODEs:

[image]

and

[image]

which you could actually solve sequentially.

Obviously you have the two unknown invariants, h and E. However, you can estimate initial guesses for these from approximate motion in a circle:

[image]

where T is the period of the orbit.

If you eliminate time t then you should get a polar curve r(theta), which represents an ellipse.